# Is my data stored in heap or in stack in below code

Tags: c, pointers, stack, malloc

In the below code, I get memory through `malloc` and pointed it by pointer `ptr`. When I assigned value as shown I stored the data in pointer and we know that pointer is located in `stack` frame.

So my question is: My data(integers) is stored in `stack` or in `heap`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
  int *ptr;
  ptr=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  ptr[0]=5;
  ptr[1]=6;
  ptr[2]=8;
  ptr[3]=10;
  ptr[4]=11;
}
```

Comment: what does malloc do? If you know the answer to that then you know the answer to your question

Comment: Vishal Mourya, "My data(integers) is stored in stack or in heap?,"My data(integers) is stored in stack or in heap?" --> _Why_ is it of interest to you?

Comment: regarding: `void main()`  There are only two valid signatures for main().  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Your compiler should have told you about this problem

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the pointer is stored on the stack, but the memory it points to is on the heap. Therefore, the integers are stored on the heap.

---

Edit to answer the question from the comments:

> Why we didn't use * like *ptr[0]=5; this means 5 store at the location
> where ptr[0] is pointing So, my question is why we didn't use *before
> ptr

In C, an array access is defined in terms of pointers. So the array element access `ptr[0]` can be written as `*ptr`. To access element `n` of the array, you can write `ptr[n]` or `*(ptr+n)`.

You would use `*ptr[0]` if your array stored *pointers* and you wanted to access the value. You can also think of that as a two-dimensional array. In other words, `*ptr[0]` is equivalent to `ptr[0][0]`.

From the [C standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Also see this question: [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Comment: Why we didn't use * like
 *ptr[0]=5;
this means 5 store at the location where ptr[0] is pointing 
So, my question is why we didn't use *before ptr

Answer (score 0):

Pedantically speaking, from the perspective of the C standard, all the objects involved here simply occupy *some memory* that is suitably aligned, and disjointed from other objects.

While the notion of a stack and heap are commonplace, the C standard makes no reference to either terms. How and where data is stored is mostly implementation-defined.

The principle thing differentiating them is their visibility and effective lifetimes (see: [Storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration), [Lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime), and [Scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope)):

- The use of `ptr` is valid until `main` returns.
- The use of the memory at the address returned by `malloc` is valid *until it is deallocated*.

---

Practically speaking, however, it is generally fair to refer to objects with

- ***automatic** storage duration* as existing on the "stack",
- ***static** storage duration* as existing in the "data segment", and
- ***allocated** storage duration* as existing on the "heap",

as this a very common way C implementations work.

With this terminology, the object designated by the identifier `ptr` exists on the *stack*, and the objects accessed via the pointer returned by `malloc` exist on the *heap*.

Comment: Re “existing on the "heap": If a memory management implementation uses a heap, then it is where free blocks of memory are kept. When memory is allocated, a block (or a part of it) is taken **off** the heap and provided for use. So allocated memory is off the heap, not on or in it. When `free` is called, the block is returned to the heap to be available for later reallocation. Generally “heap” should not be used for this, as it is a name for data structure and associated algorithms, not for memory management, and memory management does not necessarily use a heap data structure.

Comment: @EricPostpischil While I don't disagree, we're treading in hair-splitting territory, as "heap" is very often used to plainly and generally describe where dynamically allocated memory resides. There are no end of articles, learning resources, and [Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+heap), that conflate the two. I did try to separate the answer into the pedantic and practical, but would "existing on memory sourced (from|via) the heap" be a more satisfying description?

Comment: Just call it “dynamically allocated memory”. (The C standard calls it “allocated storage” but also uses “allocated” to refer to memory reservations generally, whether static, automatic, thread, or dynamic.) Some implementations of `malloc` *et al* use “zone” or “pool” to describe some of their memory management, but there is no reason to use implementation-specific terms at all. Yes, there is plenty of material that uses the term “heap.” That is no reason not to improve the practice. Using a correct clear term is better than use a widespread sloppy term.